# Long polling jQuery doesn't work in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

$.ajax seems to not work in IE. What should I do or it's just another bug in IE? Do I need to provide my code here to receive help? Because it seems it doesn't work with any $.ajax example.

My code:

```
function get_info(lines) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        url:  "chat.php?RandomNumber=" + Math.random(),
        data: "type=get_info&lines="+lines+"&RandomNumber=" + Math.random(),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(msg){
          lines = msg.lines;

          if(msg.new_messages)
          {
            for(i = 0; i < msg.messages.length; i++)
            {
                $('.chat').append("<p>"+msg.messages[i]+"</p>");      
            }
            document.getElementById('chatty').scrollTop = document.getElementById('chatty').scrollHeight;
          }
        },
        complete: function() {
            setTimeout(get_info, 1000, lines); 
        }
    })    

};    

setTimeout(get_info, 1000, 0);
```

Comment: Please provide your code

Comment: IE can be a bit funny with AJAX. It can end up caching the page being requesting, so that updates don't come in. A way around that is to ensure each AJAX request is unique in some way. Having said that, it might be your code!

Comment: @jayp: how to make that "AJAX request is unique in some way"

Comment: The easiest way is to include a querystring that is incremented each time you make a request. Create a Javascript variable, include it in the AJAX request, and increment it each time you poll the server.

Comment: @jayp: can you create an example of that? thank you, because nothing of below is working.

Comment: I don't use jQuery, I use normal Javascript - I can create an example of that if you like!

Comment: @Cfreak: I have provided some code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I now see that you're using a form of `setTimeout` that doesn't work with IE<sup>[**1**](http://www.makemineatriple.com/2007/10/passing-parameters-to-a-function-called-with-settimeout), [**2**](http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=133553)</sup>:

```
setTimeout(myFunction,myTimeout,parameter); //does NOT work for IE
```

Instead, use an anonymous function as the argument which should call the intended function with the correct argument:

```
setTimeout(function(){myFunction(myParameter);},myTimeout);
```

So your initial call to `setTimeout` should be changed to:

```
setTimeout(function(){get_info(0);}, 1000);
```

and subsequent calls on `success` should be:

```
setTimeout(function(){get_info(lines);}, 1000);
```

---

If this is because IE is caching your GET requests, you could simply set `cache` to `false` for `jQuery.ajax()` and let jQuery handle it for you (remember to clear your cache after making this change):

```
//do this for *all* ajax requests
$.ajaxSetup ({
    cache: false
});
```

or

```
//do it for this ajax request
$.ajax ({
    cache: false,
    //..other options here
});
```

Comment: @hey I've edited my answer, I think the problem is your use of `setTimeout`, passing parameters as the last arguments to `setTimeout` doesn't seem to be supported with IE.

Comment: that is just unbelievable... Thanks. :)

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the `$.ajaxSetup ({
    cache: false
});` I had a similar problem and that did the trick.  Unwanted caching ftl :(

Answer (score 1):

Add a timestamp in your data to get rid of the IE cache.

```
    var timestamp = new Date();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/toto",
        data: { ....., timestamp: timestamp.getTime() },
        ...
    });
```

Comment: Eg, send a param like 'random_num' as `Math.random()*Math.random()`.

Comment: @Tanner Ottinger: I have edited my answer and put some code. Please check.