# Hover doesn't work in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [img:hover not working in ie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287028/imghover-not-working-in-ie)

```
.answer_button
{
    background:url(images/answer.png) no-repeat;    
    width: 160px;
    height: 30px;   
    border: none;
    margin-left: -8px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.answer_button:hover
{
    background:url(images/answer_hover.png) no-repeat;    
    width: 160px;
    height: 30px;   
}
```

What is wrong with this code? It works everywhere except IE. Thank you.

P.S. If you know IE bugs well, please help me to not go crazy and help me here either: [Long polling jQuery doesn't work in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821631/long-polling-jquery-doesnt-work-in-ie)

Comment: What version of IE are you using? Not all versions behave the same, and there are too many versions around.

Comment: If my answer below doesn't fix your problem in addition to introducing you to the sprite technique then post a URL to your problem page and I'll personally debug it and write working code for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE's hover detection differs a bit from WebKit/Gecko browsers. Check out the [hoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) jQuery plugin which normalizes some of the behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Older versions of Internet Explorer do not support `:hover` except on links. (This behaviour may persist in newer versions if you fail to have a Doctype that triggers Quirks mode (I'm not certain about this as I haven't had a reason to touch Quirks mode for many, many years).

I'm guessing you are using JavaScript to bind a click handler to some other element. Use a link instead, that will have the added bonus of being accessible without a pointing device (so people who navigate with a keyboard, breath switch, etc will be able to access it).

Comment: @BoltClock — very useful if you are paralysed from the neck down. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bsUQn1gCwmA&feature=related

Answer (score 0):

In IE, hover only works for anchors (`<a>`)

Comment: Only in IE6 and older though.

Comment: It doesn't work in the newest version...

Comment: I tend to avoid them all. IE is *evil*.

Comment: I said the same thing when **I** was 14.

Comment: ;) I stand corrected. IE6 is evil.

Comment: Banish the IE http://www.ie6nomore.com/